# Google Drive API Error

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I have a problem when i share my folder to other user from mobile app using Google Drive API then it gave me error like this :

```
    {
    ": [
        {
         "domain": "global",
          "reason": "required",
          "message": "Resource metadata required"
       }
      ],
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Resource metadata required"
    }
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you added the resource metadata? Since you know, thats what the error says you need to do...

Comment: var param = {
   "role" : "writer",
   "type" : "user",
   "value" : "XYZ"
  }. i have added these resource metadata.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the whole body request you're sending? If you're using the Client Library, try to use this format instead: .insert({ role : "writer", type : "user", value : "XYZ" }, body);